How to compare 4 columns in separate dataframe and evaluate if they have the same values that matches
I would like to compare 4 columns from 2 different dataset and evaluate if they have the same values of status. is this possible to check/count how many IDNos with different status and have the same status and also what are those IDNo with different values.
sample
dataframe1
IDNO-------------Status 
P001-------------1
P002-------------2
TW01-------------1
TW02-------------0

dateframe2
IDNO-------------Status----steps 
P001-------------1------1
P001-------------1------2
P001-------------0------3   ---------> this row have different status
P002-------------2------1
P002-------------2------2
P002-------------2------3
P002-------------2------4
TW01-------------1------1
TW01-------------1------2
TW02-------------0------1

For this example IDNO "P001" has a different status.
